# Adding id attribute to dynamically created tags

Tags: javascript, jsp

This is the JSP

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_button").click(function() {
$('#left_child_layout').empty();
    var searchElement = document.getElementById("searchText").value;
    $.post("/performSearch",{searchElement:searchElement},function(responseJson){
    var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#left_child_layout')); 
        if(responseJson.length ==0){
             $('<tr>').appendTo($table)                
             .append($('<td>').text("No results")); 
        }

        $.each(responseJson, function(i,obj) {    
               $('<tr>').appendTo($table)                
                 .append($('<td>').html('<a id="names_from_search"><u>'+obj+'</u></a>')); //line 13

       });
     });
   });
});
```

So in line 13 I have a `<a>` tag with Id attribute but it doesn't seem to work when I write a `click` function corresponding to that id.

For example when I write

```
$("#names_from_search").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

I think I'm going wrong in specifying the id. What is the way to specify the same?

Comment: You shouldn't be using IDs if you're going to iteratively use it in `<tr>` elements. ID's can only exist once on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```
 $.each(responseJson, function(i,obj) {    
           $('<tr>').appendTo($table)                
             .append($('<td>').html('<a id="names_from_search" onclick="return testClick(this);"><u>'+obj+'</u></a>')); //line 13

   });
```

And add the function:

```
function testClick(ref){
  alert("Hi. clicked " + $(ref).html() + " || "+$(ref).text());
  return false;
```

}

Comment: This will work. But I also need the value of `obj` contained in the `<a>` tag ? Can I pass it as a parameter to the function `testClick()`?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating many  tags in loop and you are assigning same **id** to  everyone

You need to **assign unique id** to every  tag like below

```
 var count = 0;  

 $.each(responseJson, function(i,obj) {    
           $('<tr>').appendTo($table)                
             .append($('<td>').html('<a id="names_from_search' + count + '"  ><u>'+obj+'</u></a>')); //line 13

 count++;

   });
```

then you should have click event for every id,

Other good alternative is to bind click event to **class instead of id**.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing wrong with specifying the id. As the tags are inserted dynamically, you need to use $.on()

```
  $("#search_button").on('click', '#names_from_search', function(){
     alert("clicked");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the i argument of the each function to the id of the anchor. You could then add a class to that anchor and target those for your click event.

```
$.each(responseJson, function(i,obj) {    
    $('<tr>').appendTo($table).append($('<td>').html('<a id="names_from_search_"' + i + ' class="my-anchor"><u>'+obj+'</u></a>'));
});

$('.my-anchor').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```